# Activate only the newly created breakpoints in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode6, breakpoints

let's say I have a dozen of breakpoints here and there and I deactivated them cuz I don't need them right now. If I want to debug just a few new lines and I added breakpoints for these lines of code, as soon as I add the first breakpoint.. all of the deactivated breakpoints get activated. Is there a way to activate only these new breakpoints and keep the old ones deactivated, If no, do you have any recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Delete old breakpoints instead of disabling them. (Right-click the breakpoint and click on 'delete breakpoint')